# Do end-game crises destroy guardians?

Tags: stellaris

In my current game, there is the Enigmatic Fortress on the other side of one of my neighbors right along their border with another empire. The Contingency has just spawned and one of their spawn sites is pretty much right next to the Fortress in between those two empires. I believe the Fortress is still currently alive as the system is unclaimed, but I don't have vision into the system.

Can the Contingency, or any end-game crisis really, attack and destroy a guardian alien like the Enigmatic Fortress? Or will they leave it alone so I can swing by later to claim it?

Comment: And just for context that isn't necessary for the question, I'm playing as some determined exterminator robots. All of my neighbors are squishy meatbags just waiting to be purged into a battery for 12 years. I have no qualms war deccing them now (despite them being in a federation) if necessary. I'd just like to hold off for a couple of years while I finish blocking the ghost signal, which has caused my economy to pretty much break even right now.

Comment: The Extra Dimensional Invaders if left unchecked can grow suffieciently powerful to be able to destroy guardians.

Comment: Oh, I have no doubt that the Contingency can destroy the Enigmatic Fortress right now @MrigankaParasar, and they just spawned a month or two ago, if they decide to move into that system. They are flying fleets north of 130k fleet power. What is not clear to me is if they will decide to take the system that no one lives in, or avoid it.

Comment: @MrigankaParasar Nobody doubts that. The question is: Will they attack guardians?

Comment: Well, I just wrapped up an aggressive war campaign against my neighbor and took nearly all of their space in order to access the Enigmatic Fortress and the nearby Contingency infestation. However, there seems to be a bug so it's not quite clear to me what the expected behavior is. There's an aggressive Contingency fleet in the system and it engages the Fortress, and then appears to reset. The Fortress only takes about 4% armor damage before the combat resets, it heals the 4% back, and then the whole cycle repeats again. So, I can fight the Fortress and a Contingency fleet at the same time.

Comment: Read my updated post. Sorry for the incorrect info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they will. I have a game going where the Enigmatic Fortress was sitting in the borders of another nation. The Contingency spawned and destroyed that nation. Yesterday I was sending my fleet down to fight the Contingency and the Enigmatic Fortress was no longer there. No other nation had the fire power to take it, so it has to be the Contingency.

EDIT: It turns out the Contingency didn't destroy the leviathan. Rather they are sitting in the same system and shooting every few seconds and then stopping They were out of my sensors range, but I thought they were in it. It appears to be a glitch. I might have been fixed in 2.0.2, but the patch notes don't mention it. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I haven't played much since 2.0.2 came out. I should probably check to see if the new patch fixed the apparent bug I was seeing where the Fortress and Contingency fleet kept engaging/disengaging without dealing any meaningful damage.

Comment: @Ellesedil  I haven't played 2.0.2 yet since I am almost done with a game and the increased starbase upkeep would wrecked my economy. It might have fixed your problem or there could have been something else causing your problem.

Comment: This may be a glitch or it may be the Contingency being forced to play like a player; if a human player attacks the Enigmatic Fortress and "defeats it", they are presented with a series of options (picking the wrong one at any step will reset the scenario and you'll have to take on the fortress again). These options require a transport ship, and then a science ship, each time; there's no way to just destroy the thing outright, AFAIK. If the Contingency doesn't have a science ship or transport ship (army) they may not be able to proceed with dismantling the fortress at all.